# Using http-builder in groovy code getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes

Tags: java, groovy

In my groovy code i have used Grapes

```
@Grapes([
   @Grab(group='org.slf4j', module='slf4j-api', version='1.6.1'),
   @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='1.0.13'),
   @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-core', version='1.0.13'),
   @Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7'),
   @Grab(group='net.sf.json-lib', module='json-lib', version='0.9')
])
```

but getting below error at runtime

```
Caught: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [download failed: commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1!commons-logging.jar, download failed: logkit#logkit;1.0.1!logkit.jar, download failed: avalon-framework#avalon-framework;4.1.3!avalon-framework.jar, download failed: javax.servlet#servlet-api;2.3!servlet-api.jar]
```

Comment: This a plain network error, are You using any proxy server?

Comment: Also try `grape -V resolve group artifact version` for more informations

Comment: yes, using proxy server and can't bypass it.
Please suggest something.

Guess by default its searching for commons-logging 1.1 but its now available in central to download

Comment: if the files you are looking for are no longer there, either use a location, where they are (e.g. `@GrabResolver`) or user newer versions, that are more likely to resolve (e.g. 1.7 of slf4j).  if your proxy is not allowing the access or your local configuration for using it does not work, then there is hardly any advice to give.

Comment: Thanks @cfrick 
I tried with grape -V resolve group artifact version
downloaded all stable versions, finally got success to run groovy with dependency
thanks Opal for swift response